# Why do A[i][j] and *((int*)A + i * n + j) give me different output?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am learning C++ pointers. My instructor mentioned that `*((int*)A + i * n + j)` is another way to linearize `A[i][j]` notation. I tried testing out it with a 2x4 2D array in this main function.

```
int main()
{
    int** A = new int* [100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        A[i] = new int[100];
    }

    //assign value
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            cin >> *((int*)A + i * 4 + j);
            //cin >> A[i][j]; //if I do this instead of the line above, I will get trash values in the output

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            cout << *((int*)A + i * 4 + j) << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
       delete[] A[i];
    delete [] A;
}
```

Sample input:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

I do not understand why when I do

```
cin >> A[i][j];
```

then

```
cout << *((int*)A + i * 4 + j) << " ";
```

It gives me trash values. Does that mean I have to `cin >> *((int*)A + i * 4 + j);` if I am gonna `cout << *((int*)A + i * 4 + j) << " ";`?

My other question is: Why must I explicitly cast `(int*)`? Why can't it be `(A + i * 4 + j)`?

Comment: `A` is `int**` which is a pointer to pointer and not a 2D array. The result is a jagged array

Comment: Because 4 != 100 and the comment above.

Comment: The trick the instructor is getting at is very similar to [the one used here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op) to map a 2D index to a 1D array. In order to use it, you need a 1D array.

Comment: `A + i * 4 + j` is `&A[i * 4 + j]`, which is an `int**`. Your cast means that you treat the `int*` that it points to as if it were an `int`, which it isn't. The "2D-to-1D" conversion you're using is misplaced; you have an array of pointers, not a "2D" array stored in a "1D" array.

Comment: It should work if you define `int A[100][100];` A different type!

Comment: `(int*)A` tells the compiler to pretend that `A` is a pointer to `int`, when in fact, it's a pointer-to-pointer-to `int`. Don't do that. Only bad things can happen.

Comment: You don't even have an array of arrays; you have a dynamic array of pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You drastically misunderstood what the instructor was trying to tell you. The keyword in their description is "notation", but they left out something important (which I'll get to in a minute)

First off, if you're instructor is telling you to do this:

```
*((int*)A + i * n + j)
```

take everything they say into question. That cast is neither necessary nor advised, and can literally do *nothing* but hide bad code. If `A` is the right type it should be sufficient to do this:

```
*(A + i*n + j)
```

and if it *isn't* the right type, you probably shouldn't be doing this in the first place (which you just found out).

Second, what your instructor did *not* tell you is that this is useful for establishing a faux multi-dimension array in the linear space of an *single* dimension array using creative indexing. The key there is *single* dimension array. The modus operandi is this:

Given the desire to map a 2D space M rows by N columns into a 1D space of M*N elements, you can do this:

```
constexpr size_t M = 10;
constexpr size_t N = 5;

int A[M*N];
A[row * N + col] = value;

// equivalent to...
*(A + row * N + col) = value;
```

Note, `row` should be in the range 0...(M-1), and `col` should be the range 0..(N-1) inclusively.

This model can be extended to more dimensions. For example, a "3D" mapping, with `L` denoting slabs, `M` denoting rows, and `N` denoting columns:

```
constexpr size_t L = 10;
constexpr size_t M = 8;
constexpr size_t N = 5;

int A[L*M*N];

A[slab * (M*N) + row * N + col] = value;

// equivalent to...
*(A + slab * (M*N) + row * N + col) = value;
```

where `slab` is in the range 0...(L-1), `row` is in the range 0...(M-1), and finally `col` is in the range 0...(N-1).

You should see a pattern forming. Any native single-dimension array can be indexed with subscripts manufactured with multi-dimension representation so long as you know the limits of each dimension, and the resulting index does *not* breach the single-dimension array bed.

Most of the time you will have no need for this, but sometimes it comes in handy, especially in C++, as it lacks runtime-VLA support that C delivers.

Therefore, the proper usage of what your instructor tried to tell you would be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    static constexpr size_t M = 2;
    static constexpr size_t N = 4;
    
    int *A = new int[M*N];
    
    //assign value
    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            std::cin >> *(A + i * N + j);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            std::cout << *(A + i * N + j) << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    
    delete [] A;
}
```

Comment: I assume the instructor wanted to discuss "true" 2x4 arrays of the kind defined by e.g. `int arr[2][4];`, for which `*(A + i*n + j)` would be wrong, or at least not accessing an int (but an `int[4]` out of bounds). Getting that right without the indexing operator is a tad trickier (I think `int n = *(*(arr+i)+j);` should do the job). The lesson intended to teach being that indexing is adding plus dereferencing.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica As their justification for the cast? Probably. Thus the specific, vital note about "of the right type". No idea why they would do that rather than just show what I did above as how multi-indexing in a single-index world can work.

Comment: True, the cast is even more off with my understanding (not only redundant but wrong). Yeah, also multiplying with n points to your interpretation.